# Timer inside Chrome extension resets everytime the extension is opened

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am learning to build a browser extension using React. This browser extension basically runs a countdown timer for a specific duration. Now after deploying the extension, I am able to start the timer but when I try to perform some other action in the browser and go back to the extension popup window, the entire app(chrome extension UI) is reset to the initial state.

Basically whenever I click on the browser extension, the popup window should reflect the current state of the timer and not reset to initial UI which is a welcome screen.

Does anyone know what am I missing here?

Here is the code repo for your reference: https://github.com/pragyes31/focus-sutra

Comment: The popup is recreated each time it's opened so you can probably just store the start time in chrome.storage.local or window.localStorage and subtract it from Date.now().

Comment: Ohh I didn't know this. In that case localstorage would control the state of the app.